# Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?

Tags: paperwork, esta, italian-citizens

I was Indian citizen by birth. Once I had Indian passport. Now I am citizen of Italy with Italian passport. Indian passport has been handed over to Indian government. Now I have only Italian passport.

How should I answer the question, yes or no?

> Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?

I want to get it right, as I previously had another passport, but I no longer have it now, or any access to it.

Comment: Are you asking about the ESTA application for travel to the US?

Comment: @Jaspal Singh Out of curiosity, why wasn’t how you must answer completely obvious to you?

Comment: Yes, I m asking about ESTA application

Answer (score 23):

The answer is obviously yes; you've had passports from another country.

The question is *very* simple. It's not asking if you have another country's passport or any other travel document at this moment, it's asking if any other country *ever* issued a passport or other travel document to you.

Comment: Furthermore, the ESTA application has a separate question about other nationalities held and other nationalities formerly held, so there's no need to be concerned that answering "yes" to this question would be taken as a claim of Indian citizenship.

Comment: But not now, I have only one passport I.a. Italian..  Now I have not Indian passport

Comment: It doesn't ask what you have now. It asks if any other state has ever issued. How is this unclear?

Comment: @vidarlo I guess Jaspal is not as fluent in English.

Comment: @Jaspal Singh The question is asking whether you’ve had a passport from any other country at any time in your life in the past up to now (ie ‘ever’). It’s not asking what passport you have now.

Comment: @JaspalSingh It does **not** just ask about **now**, it also asks about **previously**. SO the answer is yes